# reset Timer of setInterval()

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 var timer;
 chat.client.addMessage = function (data) {
     clearTimeout(timer);
     test2(data);
 };
 timer = setInterval(function () {
     console.log("working");
     test1();
 }, 5000);
```

I am trying to restart timer when ever chat.client.addMessage is executed.SetInterval is executed after every 5000ms until chat.client.addMessage is executed when ever that method is executed setInterval Function stops executing . Help will be appreciated:)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.clearInterval) instead of `clearTimeout` as clearTimeout is the inverse of [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout). You can use it in the same manner:

```
clearInterval(timer);
```

Comment: it's still not getting executed after chat.client.addMessage execution

Comment: In that case `chat.client.addMessage` likely isn't getting called. Put a `console.log` in there.

Comment: Then your issue is not with setInterval/clearInterval. Here is a fiddle of it working: http://jsfiddle.net/Blade0rz/3HWxQ/

Comment: well when I remove that cleatInterval(timer) function .Every thing works fine but setInterval time obviously is not getting reset

Comment: A little late to the party, but `clearInterval` and `clearTimeout` are [actually interchangeable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Return_value) (not that they should be used interchangeably). Not sure why this is the accepted answer since it doesn't seem to answer OP's question.

Comment: @3ocene Wow. Nearly 4 years later,but I never knew that this whole time. Thanks! In that case you're right. This answer is totally wrong.

Answer (score 8):

you need to add a function that clears the interval and then restarts it

```
function resetInterval() {
  clearInterval(timer);

  timer = setInterval(function() {
    console.log("restarted interval");
    test1();
   }, 5000); 
 }
```

then you can simply call it as needed

```
chat.client.addMessage = function(data) {
  resetInterval();
  test2(data);
};
```