# Run a script in chrome every 1 minute

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

im trying to make a script that picks 1 random class name out of 3
every 1 minute and clicks the button with the chosen class
so far i created the script that clicks on the button:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $(".btn-danger").trigger("click");
}, 100);
```

The problem is if i put it in a while(true)
the site stuck and then the browser crashes.

Also im have no idea how to make it to chose random class so i putted in one of them.

Will be glad to get some help here :D

Comment: You need a reset timer event - google it is a good start - have a look at this for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18270009/reset-timer-of-setinterval - @jfriend00 is exactly correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) to run something over and over.  You can generate a random index from 0 to 2 with `Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)`.

For example, you could select a random class name like this:

```
var classes = ["classA", "classB", "classC"];

function selectRandomArrayElement(array) {
    return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}

var rand = selectRandomArrayElement(classes);
```

So, putting it all together:

```
var classes = ["classA", "classB", "classC"];

function selectRandomArrayElement(array) {
    return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}

// click on a the object with a random class name every minute
setInterval(function() {
    var rand = selectRandomArrayElement(classes);
    $("." + rand).trigger("click");
}, 1000*60);
```

In Javascript, you can't use `while(true)` long duration loops like this block the rest of the browser from processing events and thus your the click events you trigger are never processed.  Instead, you use timers to do something repeatedly.

Comment: how can i set for example
1 = class1  , 2 = class2 etc?

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`, which will invoke the callback indefinitely at the interval you specify.

```
setInterval(function () {
  $(".btn-danger").trigger("click");
}, 60000);
```

Should work for you. `while(true)` crashes your browser because you're creating an infinite loop that blocks any other code from executing.

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout uses milliseconds and only occurs once. Use setInterval with one second * 60 to get a minute.

```
var minute = 1000 * 60;
setInterval(function() {   $(".btn-danger").trigger("click");
  }, minute);
```