# How do I stop and restart a setInterval when new date is selected

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Here you can select a date and it will tell you how long till that date. But if i pick a new date things get buggy... What should I do to restart the function and the setInterval once a new date value is selcted?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var showOne = new Date();
  var showTwo = new Date(2016, 10, 14);
  $('#showOne').text(showOne);
  $('#showTwo').text(showTwo);

  function calcDate(newDater) {

    var tickTock = setInterval(function() {
      var currentDateSec = $.now() / 1000;
      var laterDate = newDater;
      // console.log("Later Date: " + laterDate);
      var laterDateSec = laterDate / 1000;
      var timeLeft = laterDateSec - currentDateSec;

      var sLeft = Math.floor(timeLeft) % 60;
      var mLeft = Math.floor(timeLeft / (60)) % 60;
      var hLeft = Math.floor(timeLeft / (60 * 60)) % 24;
      var dLeft = Math.floor(timeLeft / (60 * 60 * 24)) % 7;
      var wLeft = Math.floor(timeLeft / (60 * 60 * 24 * 7)) % 4;
      var moLeft = Math.floor(timeLeft / (60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 4));


      $('#humandate').text(moLeft + " Month(s) - " + wLeft + " Week(s) - " + dLeft + " Day(s) - " + hLeft + " Hour(s) - " + mLeft + " Mins - " + sLeft + " Sec\(s\)");


    }, 1000);

  }


  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {

      var dateAsString = dateText; //the first parameter of this function
      var dateAsObject = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); //the getDate method
      var date = $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd,MM,yyyy'
      }).val();
      console.log(dateAsString + " --- " + dateAsObject + " --- " + date);
      calcDate(dateAsObject);
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js "></script>

<p>Date:
  <input type="text" id="datepicker">
</p>

<span id="humandate"></span>
<br/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reset Timer of setInterval()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18270009/reset-timer-of-setinterval)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reset it by doing a `clearInterval(id)` like:

```
...

var tickTock;

function calcDate(newDater) {
    // if you have set it before, clear it.
    if (tickTock) {
        clearInterval(tickTock);
    }
    tickTock = setInterval(function() {
    ....
```

Comment: I got no luck with this, unless I am still missing something

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it with:

```
...

function calcDate(newDater) {

    $("#datepicker").on( 'blur' , function(){ clearInterval(tickTock); });

    var tickTock = setInterval(function() {

...
```